# Как получть доступ к элементу pop up button в swift и использовать его в вычислениях?

Tags: swift

Я новичек в swift. Написал код для вычисления. Не пойму как получить доступ к элементу popup button, который выбран и использовать его в вычислениях?
Вот код:

```
//  GlasgoScaleCalculatorViewController.swift
//  MedicalCalc
//
//  Created by Andrei Dokuchaev on 30.12.2022.
//

import UIKit

class GlasgoScaleCalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       setPopUpButton()
      
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectHumanOutlet: UISegmentedControl!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var otkrivanieGlas: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rechevayaReakciya: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dvigatelnayaReakciya: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var resultKomaField: UILabel!
    
    
    func setPopUpButton() {
        
        let optionClosure = {(action : UIAction) in
            print(action.title)}
        
    
        otkrivanieGlas.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Отсутствует", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Реакция на боль", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Реакция на голос", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Произвольное", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
        
    
        otkrivanieGlas.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        otkrivanieGlas.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        
        
        rechevayaReakciya.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Отсутствие речи", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Нечленораздельные звуки в ответ на заданный вопрос", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Словесная окрошка, ответ по смыслу не соответствует вопросу", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Больной дезориентирован, спутанная речь", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Больной ориентирован, быстрый и правильный ответ на заданный вопрос", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
    
        rechevayaReakciya.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        rechevayaReakciya.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        
        dvigatelnayaReakciya.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Отсутствие движений", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Патологическое разгибание в ответ на болевое раздражение", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Патологическое сгибание в ответ на болевое раздражение", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Отдёргивание конечности в ответ на болевое раздражение", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Целенаправленное движение в ответ на болевое раздражение (отталкивание)", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Выполнение движений по команде", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
    
        dvigatelnayaReakciya.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        dvigatelnayaReakciya.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
    
    }
    
    
    func setPopUpButtonChildren() {
        
        let optionClosure = {(action : UIAction) in
            print(action.title)}
        
    
        otkrivanieGlas.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Отсутствует", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Реакция на боль", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Реакция на голос", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Произвольное", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
        
    
        otkrivanieGlas.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        otkrivanieGlas.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        
        
        rechevayaReakciya.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Плач и интерактивность отсутствуют", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Не успокаивается при плаче, беспокоен", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "При плаче успокаивается, но ненадолго, стонет", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Ребёнка при плаче можно успокоить, интерактивность неполноценная", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Ребёнок улыбается, ориентируется на звук, следит за объектами, интерактивен", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
    
        rechevayaReakciya.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        rechevayaReakciya.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        
        dvigatelnayaReakciya.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Отсутствие движений", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Патологическое разгибание в ответ на болевое раздражение", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Патологическое сгибание в ответ на болевое раздражение", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Отдёргивание конечности в ответ на болевое раздражение", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Целенаправленное движение в ответ на болевое раздражение (отталкивание)", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Выполнение движений по команде", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
    
        dvigatelnayaReakciya.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        dvigatelnayaReakciya.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
    
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectHumanAction(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        
        switch selectHumanOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex {
            
        case 0:
            setPopUpButton()
        case 1 :
            setPopUpButtonChildren()
        default:
            break
            
        }
        
    }
    
    var otkrivanGlasSelected: Double = 0
    
    var rechevayaReakciaSelected: Double = 0
    
    var dvigatelReakciyaSelected: Double = 0
    
    var resultKomaGlasgoSelect: String = ""

 @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    
     // вычисления по нажатию кнопки
         
     }
    
    }
    
}
```

Метод selectedSegmentIndex не работает так как отсутствует в UIButton. Помогите, пожалуйта.

Comment: `sender: Any` и есть тот, на ком событие сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил сам. Через currentTitle.